# SQL Server CTE, How do I use the CTE table again for GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

`TableX` with columns and values

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   Level
---------------------------------------------------------------------
10  ABC 10  ABC XYZ 2   3   4   1
10  ABC 10  ABC XYZ 2   3   4   1
11  DEF 10  ABC XYZ 4   5   6   2
11  DEF 10  ABC XYZ 6   7   8   2
12  GHI 11  DEF XYZ 7   8   9   3
12  GHI 11  DEF XYZ 8   9   10  3
15  JKL 15  JKL ABC 9   10  11  1
15  JKL 15  JKL ABC 10  11  12  1
16  MNO 15  JKL ABC 13  14  15  2
16  MNO 15  JKL ABC 16  16  18  2
```

Here the `Level` is not a column in the table, I just added for clarity but will be automatically inferred by CTE by comparing A, B with C and D

For Level 1 the calculation will be

```
Calc1 = (F + G - H)  
Calc2 = Calc1 + G + H
```

Level 2 and onwards the calculation formula is

Calc1 = Sum of (Calc2 Of Previous Level) / 100
Calc2 = Calc1 + G + H - There is no change for this calculation irrespective of Level

`The calculation is cyclic` - The calculation result of Level 2 will need to be fed to Level 3 calculation and so on..

```
WITH Tiers (
     Level,
     A,
     B,
     C,
     D,
     E,
     Calc1,
     Calc2)
AS
SELECT 1 AS Level,
       A,
       B,
       C,
       D,
       E,
       F + G - H AS Calc1,
       (F + G - H) + G + H AS Calc2
 FROM TableX
WHERE A = C
  AND B = D
UNION ALL
SELECT tier.Level + 1 AS Level,
       A,
       B,
       C,
       D,
       E,
       /* How can I do this SUM (tier.Calc1) / 100 */
       /* How can I do this SUM (tier.Calc1) / 100 + G + H */
 FROM TableX tab
 INNER JOIN Tiers tier
    ON tab.C = tier.A
   AND tab.D = tier.B
   AND tab.E = tier.E
WHERE (A <> C
   OR B <> D)
)
SELECT *
  FROM Tiers
```

I tried

```
SELECT tier.Level + 1 AS Level,
       A,
       B,
       C,
       D,
       E,
       sumCalc.calc1 / 100 Calc1
       sumCalc.calc1 / 100 + G + H Calc2
 FROM TableX tab
 INNER JOIN Tiers tier
    ON tab.C = tier.A
   AND tab.E = tier.B
 INNER JOIN (
      SELECT A, B, E, SUM(Calc1) Calc1
        FROM Tiers
      GROUP BY A, B, E) sumCalc /* SQL Server throws error that CTE table cannot be used here */
WHERE (A <> C
   OR B <> D)
```

I am also looking to using table-valued OUTER APPLY or something ..

Comment: try using Tiers there instead of tier

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo, updated

Comment: If I understand your question, you don't need `SUM()`.  You simply accumulate the values by adding them in the second half of the CTE.  `Level` isn't a `SUM()`, it is the total of a series of additions.

Comment: @user92546 sorry I don't understand your answer, could you tell me how to accumulate? I need the value as well as the accumulated SUM.

Comment: @Humble - Do you really want the `SUM()` of _all_ rows at the previous level, or just one row?  The first case is a challenge, the second is handled just like `Level`: `Tiers.Calc1 + ( G + H ) / 100`.  Is there a typo in your `Calc1` definition?  The description refers to sum of `Calc2` but the code uses `Calc1'.

Comment: Yes, I need to do SUM I know that is challenging, and the Calc1 and 2 of that Level N value need to be fed into the UNION so the next level can refer them again with SUM.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: After fiddling with CTEs, including multiple CTEs rolled together, it doesn't look promising.

The following code uses a CTE to assign the levels and handle the level 1 calculations and saves the results in a temporary table.  A loop then processes each additional level in order.  I'm still a little addled (in general and) about the grouping for the SUMs, but that should be easy to tweak.

```
 declare @TableX as Table ( A Int, B VarChar(3), C Int, D VarChar(3), E VarChar(3), F Int, G Int, H Int )

 insert into @TableX ( A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H ) values
   ( 10, 'ABC', 10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 2,  3,  4 ),
   ( 10, 'ABC', 10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 2,  3,  4 ),
   ( 11, 'DEF', 10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 4,  5,  6 ),
   ( 11, 'DEF', 10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 6,  7,  8 ),
   ( 12, 'GHI', 11, 'DEF', 'XYZ', 7,  8,  9 ),
   ( 12, 'GHI', 11, 'DEF', 'XYZ', 8,  9,  10 ),
   ( 15, 'JKL', 15, 'JKL', 'ABC', 9,  10, 11 ),
   ( 15, 'JKL', 15, 'JKL', 'ABC', 10, 11, 12 ),
   ( 16, 'MNO', 15, 'JKL', 'ABC', 13, 14, 15 ),
   ( 16, 'MNO', 15, 'JKL', 'ABC', 16, 16, 18 )

-- Create a temporary table with levels assigned and the level 1 calculations performed.
; with Tiers ( Level, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, Calc1, Calc2 )
  as (
    -- Level 1.
    select 1, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, Cast( F + G - H as Float ), Cast( ( F + G - H ) + G + H as Float )
      from @TableX
      where A = C and B = D
    union all
    -- Level > 1.
    select T.Level + 1, TX.A, TX.B, TX.C, TX.D, TX.E, TX.F, TX.G, TX.H, NULL, NULL
      from @TableX as TX inner join
        Tiers as T on T.A = TX.C and T.B = TX.D and T.E = TX.E
      where TX.A <> TX.C or TX.B <> TX.D
    )
  select *
    into #Tiers
    from Tiers

-- Perform the additional calculations one level at a time.
declare @MinLevel as Int
select @MinLevel = Min( Level )
  from #Tiers
  where Calc1 is NULL

while @MinLevel is not NULL
  begin
  -- Note: The   SELECTs   for the sums may need extended   WHERE   clauses to implement the desired grouping.
  update #Tiers
    set Calc1 = ( select Sum( Calc2 ) from #Tiers where Level = @MinLevel - 1 ) / 100,
      Calc2 = ( select Sum( Calc2 ) from #Tiers where Level = @MinLevel - 1 ) / 100 + G + H
    where Level = @MinLevel
  select @MinLevel = Min( Level )
    from #Tiers
    where Calc1 is NULL
  end

-- Display the results.
select *
  from #Tiers
  order by Level

-- Houseclean.    
drop table #Tiers
```

---

*First attempt retained below for completeness:*

Perhaps the solution is to do all of the `Calc1`/`Calc2` calculations after building the CTE:

```
 declare @TableX as Table ( A Int, B VarChar(3), C Int, D VarChar(3), E VarChar(3), F Int, G Int, H Int )

 insert into @TableX ( A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H ) values
   ( 10, 'ABC', 10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 2,  3,  4 ),
   ( 10, 'ABC', 10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 2,  3,  4 ),
   ( 11, 'DEF', 10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 4,  5,  6 ),
   ( 11, 'DEF', 10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 6,  7,  8 ),
   ( 12, 'GHI', 11, 'DEF', 'XYZ', 7,  8,  9 ),
   ( 12, 'GHI', 11, 'DEF', 'XYZ', 8,  9,  10 ),
   ( 15, 'JKL', 15, 'JKL', 'ABC', 9,  10, 11 ),
   ( 15, 'JKL', 15, 'JKL', 'ABC', 10, 11, 12 ),
   ( 16, 'MNO', 15, 'JKL', 'ABC', 13, 14, 15 ),
   ( 16, 'MNO', 15, 'JKL', 'ABC', 16, 16, 18 )

; with Tiers ( Level, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H )
  as (
    -- Level 1.
    select 1, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
      from @TableX
      where A = C and B = D
    union all
    -- Level > 1.
    select T.Level + 1, TX.A, TX.B, TX.C, TX.D, TX.E, TX.F, TX.G, TX.H
      from @TableX as TX inner join
        Tiers as T on T.A = TX.C and T.B = TX.D and T.E = TX.E
      where TX.A <> TX.C or TX.B <> TX.D
    )
  select *,
    case Level
      when 1 then T.F + T.G - T.H
      else ( select Sum( F + G - H ) / 100. from Tiers where Level = T.Level - 1 ) end as Calc1,
    case Level
      when 1 then ( T.F + T.G - T.H ) + T.G + T.H
      else ( select Sum( F + G - H ) / 100. + T.G + T.H from Tiers where Level = T.Level - 1 ) end as Calc2
    from Tiers as T
    order by Level
```

Note that I added a decimal point so that the resulting calculations would return real values.

Comment: Thanks @user92546 for spending time. But there is a catch to the calculations, they are cyclic. If the see, calculation1 is SUM (Calculation2 of previous level) and then Calculation2 is again referring Calculation1 we just calculated. In your answer you are doing two separate SUM, in this case calculation value for next level will not have access to the updated Calc1 and Calc2 of the previous level because we are calculating and not putting the value back to the table so next level will refer them. Hope I am able to explain the situation.

Comment: I updated the original question and mentioned about the cyclic nature.

Comment: And I missed the GROUP BY in the SUM query, in your SELECT CASE also we need the get all the matching A, B and E records and do GROUP BY A, B, E for the SUM

Comment: Another issue, we can't use GROUP BY, getting error "GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression"